# Alternate (preferably Free) iOS App like Charles Proxy App

Tags: ios, iphone-app, network-monitor, vpn

I'm looking for an alternate App (preferably Free) like Charles Proxy for iOS. The only features expected:

- View SSL requests as plain text
- Take action besides monitoring, like block / alter requests for configured URLs for app testing
- Absolutely must to support **cellular network** (including wifi)
- Capture and share to desktop for any further debugging (less priority)

So far I've explored options using similar network monitoring tool using Charles Proxy (desktop trial version), Fiddler, etc using wifi. The biggest issue is I've to be present in office (or both devices on same network), which isn't feasible option for me.

There are many options available in market for desktop or testing mobile Apps using these tools using wifi, but I hardly find any iOS app which does natively same thing on the device. I see there are tons of VPN apps / services available, which has other issues like data privacy, cost, etc. The Charles Proxy for iOS app seems a good option as it monitors network traffic through local VPN, but it is neither free nor there's a trial option available.

Please let me know if there's any. Thanks in Advance!